# AWS quicksight API create-data-source for JIRA throws an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to create a new JIRA data source using the AWS CLI command at `https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/create-data-source.html`.

I am using the `DataSourceParameters` field as described by the documentation.

Using below json file as command input:

```
{
    "AwsAccountId": "----my-account-id-------",
    "DataSourceId": "jira2253",
    "Name": "jirasourceee",
    "Type": "JIRA",
    "DataSourceParameters": {
         "JiraParameters": {
            "SiteBaseUrl": "https://-----my-jira----/"
        }
    },
    "Credentials": {
        "CredentialPair": {
            "Username": "----",
            "Password": "----"
        }
    }
}
```

But still getting the error `An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateDataSource operation: DataSourceParameters field is incorrectly set`

Comment: Got the same issue while deploying using Terraform. But I can create it without problem if I'm using the QuickSight GUI. Must be a bug in their API.

Comment: Yes, I contacted AWS support, and they confirmed that this is not available in their API, works via the console.